# thraxcompiler error while loading shared libraries: libthrax.so.0

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, openfst, thrax-grammer, thrax-compiler

I have installed openfst and thraxcompiler successfully. thraxmakedep creates the make file successfully

```
thraxOpenGrm/thrax-1.1.0/src/grammars$ thraxmakedep example.grm
```

after the make file is created, when i run make i get the following error

```
thraxOpenGrm/thrax-1.1.0/src/grammars$ make
thraxcompiler --input_grammar=byte.grm --output_far=byte.far
thraxcompiler: error while loading shared libraries: libthrax.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make: *** [byte.far] Error 127
```

But the library is present in the path:

```
/usr/local/lib/libthrax.so.0
```

I tried a few steps which works for gcc compiler like
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` , use flags like `-Wl,-rpath` , `-Llib` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue occurs due to the Thrax Compiler not able to find the required libraries. Executing the command `sudo ldconfig` fixes it.

Alternately it can be fixed by copying that library(libthrax.so.0) in `/usr/lib/`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to set this so it can find the shared library:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

Comment: I tried this but it's a temporary solution. I've to set it everytime I restart